# Printing named parameters

Tags: erlang

Archaelus suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383407/what-are-some-interesting-projects-to-solve-in-erlang-for-learning-purposes#383456) that writing a new format routine to handle named parameters may be a good learning exercise. So, in the spirit of learning the language I wrote a formatting routine which handles named parameters.

**An Example:**

```
1> fout:format("hello ~s{name}, ~p{one}, ~p{two}, ~p{three}~n",[{one,1},{three,3},{name,"Mike"},{two,2}]).
hello Mike, 1, 2, 3
ok
```

**The Benchmark:**

```
1> timer:tc(fout,benchmark_format_overhead,["hello ~s{name}, ~p{one}, ~p{two}, ~p{three}~n",[{one,1},{name,"Mike"},{three,3},{two,2}],100000]).
{421000,true}
= 4.21us per call
```

Although I suspect that much of this overhead is due to looping, as a calling the function with one loop yields a response in < 1us.

```
1> timer:tc(fout,benchmark_format_overhead,["hello ~s{name}, ~p{one}, ~p{two}, ~p{three}~n",[{one,1},{name,"Mike"},{three,3},{two,2}],1]).
{1,true}
```

If there is a better way of benchmarking in erlang, please let me know.

**The Code:**
(which has been revised in accordance with Doug's suggestion)

```
-module(fout).

-export([format/2,benchmark_format_overhead/3]).

benchmark_format_overhead(_,_,0)->
    true;
benchmark_format_overhead(OString,OList,Loops) ->
    {FString,FNames}=parse_string(OString,ONames),
    benchmark_format_overhead(OString,OList,Loops-1).

format(OString,ONames) ->
    {FString,FNames}=parse_string(OString,ONames),
    io:format(FString,FNames).

parse_string(FormatString,Names) ->
    {F,N}=parse_format(FormatString),
    {F,substitute_names(N,Names)}.

parse_format(FS) ->
    parse_format(FS,"",[],"").

parse_format("",FormatString,ParamList,"")->
    {lists:reverse(FormatString),lists:reverse(ParamList)};
parse_format([${|FS],FormatString,ParamList,"")->
    parse_name(FS,FormatString,ParamList,"");
parse_format([$}|_FS],FormatString,_,_) ->
    throw({'unmatched } found',lists:reverse(FormatString)});
parse_format([C|FS],FormatString,ParamList,"") ->
    parse_format(FS,[C|FormatString],ParamList,"").

parse_name([$}|FS],FormatString,ParamList,ParamName) ->
    parse_format(FS,FormatString,[list_to_atom(lists:reverse(ParamName))|ParamList],"");
parse_name([${|_FS],FormatString,_,_) ->
    throw({'additional { found',lists:reverse(FormatString)});
parse_name([C|FS],FormatString,ParamList,ParamName) ->
    parse_name(FS,FormatString,ParamList,[C|ParamName]).

substitute_names(Positioned,Values) ->
    lists:map(fun(CN)->
                        case lists:keysearch(CN,1,Values) of
                            false ->
                                throw({'named parameter not found',CN,Values});
                            {_,{_,V}} ->
                                V
                        end end,
              Positioned).
```

As this was a learning exercise, I was hoping that those more experienced with erlang could give me tips on how to improve my code.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: For timing purposes, if it is too fast to measure, you should run it in a loop and take the average as the time

Comment: please rephrase your question in the title, i wouldn't know what you were asking if I saw it in search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without comment on the algorithm, or on use of appropriate library functions...

I would have expected to see more use of pattern matching and recursion; for example parse_character (no longer folded) might be replaced with something like:

```
parse_in_format ([], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> {FmtStr, ParmStrs};
parse_in_format ([${ | Vr], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> parse_in_name (Vr, FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName);
parse_in_format ([$} | Vr], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> throw() % etc.
parse_in_format ([V | Vr], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> parse_in_format (Vr, [V | FmtStr], ParmStrs, ParmName).

parse_in_name ([], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> throw() % etc.
parse_in_name ([$} | Vr], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> parse_in_format (Vr, FmtStr, [list_to_atom(lists:reverse(ParmName))|ParmStrs], "");
parse_in_name ([${ | Vr], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> throw() % etc.
parse_in_name ([V | Vr], FmtStr, ParmStrs, ParmName) -> parse_in_name (Vr, FmtStr, ParmStrs, [V | ParmName]).
```

Kicked off with a

```
parse_in_format (FormatStr,  [], [], "");
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, I agree that that method is superior, I'm rewriting it at the moment using fewer library functions.

Erlang is my first functional language so I am still transitioning into functional thinking.

Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to doug's suggestion, I'd avoid using `atom_to_list/1` here - the substitute names code doesn't need them and generating atoms at runtime is almost always a bad idea. Strings will work perfectly well.

```
parse_name([$}|FS],FormatString,ParamList,ParamName) ->
    parse_format(FS,FormatString,[lists:reverse(ParamName)|ParamList],"");
parse_name([${|_FS],FormatString,_,_) ->
    throw({'additional { found',lists:reverse(FormatString)});
parse_name([C|FS],FormatString,ParamList,ParamName) ->
    parse_name(FS,FormatString,ParamList,[C|ParamName]).
```

I would also use proplists:get_value instead of `lists:keysearch/3` - when you have a list of two element tuples `{Name, Value}` as we do here, using the `proplists` code is the way to go - it's still a little messy as we need the case statement to check for missing values so we can crash with a better error.

```
substitute_names(Positioned,Values) ->
    [ case proplists:get_value(Name, Values) of
          undefined -> erlang:exit({missing_parameter, Name});
          V -> V
      end
      || Name <- Positioned ].
```

As this is a library, it should be a replacement for `io_lib`, not `io`. This way we don't have to provide all the alternatives `io` offers (optional `IoDevice` argument and so on).

```
format(OString,ONames) ->
    {FString,FNames}=parse_string(OString,ONames),
    io_lib:format(FString,FNames).
```

All in all, solid code. If you're willing to license it under BSD or something similar, I'd quite like to add it to my web framework code [Ejango](http://github.com/archaelus/ejango/tree/master).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, I've been on holiday for the past 2 weeks.


Thank you for your detailed suggestions and explanations, they were most helpful.


I am happy to license the code under BSD, so feel free to use it however you wish (and with whatever modifications you wish).


Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know if looping overhead affect your code much you should measure it. It's simple.

```
-define(COLOOPS, 1000000).

-export([call_overhead/1,measure_call_overhead/0, measure_call_overhead/1]).

% returns overhead in us 
measure_call_overhead() -> measure_call_overhead(?COLOOPS).
measure_call_overhead(N) -> element(1, timer:tc(?MODULE, call_overhead, [N]))/N.

call_overhead(0)->ok;
call_overhead(N)->
    ok=nop(),
    call_overhead(N-1).

nop()->ok.
```

It is about 50ns on my laptop. I think this should not affect your current code so much.

Another way how to measure is using directly statistics(wall_clock) or statistics(runtime) which returns time in ms. Benefit is that you don't need export measured function. It is only cosmetics improvement.